# Exclude .svn directory from bitbake

Tags: git, svn

I'm new to embedded. I'm having a freescale ls1021a-iot rev1 board, and yocto sdk v1.8. I've checkout the sdk from svn. Due to the .svn directory, bitbake doesn't  work properly. If I delete all .svn directories in git directory using ' find . -name .svn | xargs rm -fr'  bitbake works, but this will affect synchronization with  SVN. How is it possible to bitbake 'virtual/kernel' as well as image with out deleting .svn directory?

Thanks
Pranav

Comment: you have to ignore your svn directory. try this: `echo .svn >> .gitignore`

Answer (score 0):

You should only be using 1 VCS if you need both I would suggest looking at git-svn https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion

The main repository will remain in svn but you can also use gits features

Comment: I've already checkout the sdk from svn. while compiling the sdk, the problem is arising.
ERROR: QA Issue: Architecture did not match (40 to 62) on /work/ls1021aiot-fsl-linux-gnueabi/linux-ls1/3.12-r0/packages-split/kernel-dev/usr/src/kernel/usr/.svn/text-base/gen_init_cpio.svn-base
ERROR: QA Issue: Architecture did not match (40 to 62) on /work/ls1021aiot-fsl-linux-gnueabi/linux-ls1/3.12-r0/packages-split/kernel-dev/usr/src/kernel/scripts/dtc/.svn/text-base/dtc.svn-base

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like a problem cause by the VCS more a problem with the code ?